# ValueError happened when import a compiled Cython function

Tags: python, c++, c, cpython

I want to use a Cpython function stated as below:

```
# distutils: language = c
# cython: language_level=3

cimport numpy as np 
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double sqrt(double x)

def sigma_update(double sigma, double sigmamax, double sigmamin, double prim_win, double dual_win, int iter, int innerop):
    cdef double sigmascale = 5.0
    cdef int sigma_update_iter, i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] sigma_array = np.array([sigma])
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] prim_win_array = np.array([prim_win])
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] dual_win_array = np.array([dual_win])
    
    if iter < 10:
        sigma_update_iter = 1
    elif iter < 20:
        sigma_update_iter = 2
    elif iter < 200:
        sigma_update_iter = 2
    elif iter < 500:
        sigma_update_iter = 3
    else:
        sigma_update_iter = 3
    
    if innerop == 1:
        sigmascale = sqrt(5.0)
    
    if iter % sigma_update_iter == 0:
        if prim_win > max(1, 1.2*dual_win):
            prim_win = 0.0
            sigma = min(sigmamax, sigma*sigmascale)
        elif dual_win > max(1, 3*prim_win):
            dual_win = 0.0
            sigma = max(sigmamin, 2*sigma/sigmascale)
    
    return np.array([sigma]), np.array([prim_win]), np.array([dual_win])
```

when I import it after compiling the pyx file, I get the following error:
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 80 from PyObject.

The current Cython's version is 0.29.34 and numpy's version is 1.20.3. After I uninstall and install the packages for many times, it doesn't work either. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide more details (commands, build files) on how you build your extension.

Comment: Anyway, i can't reproduce.